# MD5 Hash mismatch after Object Compression

Tags: object, md5, compression, mismatch

I am compressing a Serializable Object using following snippet:

```
 private byte[] compressObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOut);
    objectOut.writeObject(obj);     
    objectOut.close();
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    return bytes;       
}
```

And decompressing the same object using following snippet:

```
private Object decompressObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    GZIPInputStream gzipIn = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(gzipIn);
    Object obj = objectIn.readObject();     
    objectIn.close();

    return obj;
}
```

Before compressing the Object and after decompressing the Object, I calculate the MD5 Hash using following snippet:

```
public String getMD5Hash(Object obj) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
    out.writeObject(obj);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();                
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");                     
    m.update(data,0,data.length);
    BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1,m.digest());
    return String.format("%1$032X", i);     
}
```

But the MD5 Hash calculated before compression and after compression does not match. Kindly suggest how to get the Object as it is after decompression.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get to solve that? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the finish method on the GZIPOutputStream to get it to compress the data.

Comment: Hi Mark, this didn't help. Can you suggest some other pointers?